# Custom Imports in star schema

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I have a Dataware house with star schema.
The client is looking forward for import of csv file along with their relationship. Which will be provided by an import tool).
They are looking for operation database like structure (parent ,children) in existing star schema system.It is more like a snowflake or starflake more precisely.

What are the best practices in this situation:
1. I can't stop them importing.
2. I can set the standards in import tool, but I would need to list them.
3. How to handle many to many relationships.
4. I have ETL as well, so what need to be done in ETL to not break the existing relationship

Comment: Normal practice would be to transform parent-child type data  into a flattened dimensional table with columns representing each level of the relationship. There are design reasons for using a star schema  and you probably need to explain those to your client.

Comment: What you mean by " transform parent-child type data into a flattened dimensional table" any example ?

Comment: Here's an example that I googled: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1071035-392-1.aspx. Basically it means instead of a single self referencing table (that can have an infinite depth), you create a table which 'instantiates' the levels into fields. So You have a table with columns 'Root', 'Level1','Level2','Level3','Level4','Level5','Level6','Level7'. etc. It limits the number of levels you can have but it makes it far easier to represent in a star schema and gives all the benefits of a star schema.

Comment: There are a lot of other factors that should influence your design. Will departing from a star schema cause issues in the future? What is your BI / Presentation tool? This is really a database design question which means you will have some people emotionally attached to certain types of designs. You're not going to get a good answer on this unless you describe some other design constraints such as: what is your BI and ETL tool? Do you have the skills to build and maintain certain solutions (in ETL or BI)?